# How do I install and setup MinGW 4.6 for Qt?

Tags: qt, installation, mingw

I've been looking for precise instructions on how to install and setup MinGW 4.6 for Qt 4.7 to no avail. I have no clue as to which MinGW 4.6 packages I have to grab and how to set them up. Qt seems to provide a 'customized' version of MinGW 4.4 with Creator 2.1.0, so it's difficult for me to make an accurate guess based on it. Has anyone done this before? Which packages do I need?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the official [Qt SDK](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/05/04/qt-sdk-1-1-released/) with MinGW and everything you need included? If you don't like to install the SDK here is a list of the used packages that come with the SDK:

- binutils-2.19.1-mingw32-bin
- mingwrt-3.15.2-mingw32-dev
- mingwrt-3.15.2-mingw32-dll
- w32api-3.13-mingw32-dev
- gcc-core-4.4.0-mingw32-bin
- gcc-core-4.4.0-mingw32-dll
- gcc-c++-4.4.0-mingw32-bin
- gcc-c++-4.4.0-mingw32-dll
- gmp-4.2.4-mingw32-dll
- libiconv-1.13-mingw32-dll-2
- mingw32-make-3.81-20080326-3
- mpfr-2.4.1-mingw32-dll
- pthreads-w32-2.8.0-mingw32-dll
- gdb and libexpat-1.dll

That's a section from the *manifest.txt* inside the QtSDK\mingw folder, some of the packages are further modified or patched so I guess it would be much easier to use the SDK instead or maybe a different compiler. You can also use the Microsoft C++ Compiler (MSVC) besides others compatible with Qt.